# Domain Name is not being resolved after changing from WIndows to Linux App service Plan

Tags: azure, dns, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

Earlier we had Windows App Service Plan and App services within the plan have VNet-integration enabled to connect to on-premises services. It used to reach on-premises services from the app service by resolving the domain names.

Recently Microsoft announced that regional VNet-integration for Linux App Services feature is Generally Available. we tried to migrate all our windows app services to Linux. Fortunately, we did not face any issues with subnet-delegation. But after the migration, the Linux app services are not able to reach on-premises service. It says UnknownHostException from the java code and tried from Kudo console, there also it says domain name is not being resolved. and we noticed that logs are not being pushed to Application Insights.

The next day, we just tried with IP address instead of domain names, it worked. For Application Insights, we could not do anything. To just confirm for Application Insights, we disconnected the vnet-integration for app service, then the app is able to send logs to application insights.

So what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, all of a sudden it got resolved by itself. And when we asked Microsoft Support, its mentioned that they have done recent network update in their backbone network.

Since we did not know what was the issue, we did not migrate Win to Linux in our higher env, we rollback to Windows and there was no issue after that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Linux Web App in an App Service plan already hosting non-Linux Web Apps. I suppose you have created new app service plan and app service for Linux to manage [regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration).

> Your app cannot resolve addresses in **Azure DNS Private Zones** without
> configuration changes
>
> The feature is fully supported for both Windows and Linux web apps.
> All of the behaviors act the same between Windows apps and Linux apps.

Also, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

In the scenario of name resolution from App Service Web Apps in one virtual network to VMs in a different virtual network, it requires **customer-managed DNS servers forwarding queries between virtual networks for resolution by Azure (DNS proxy)**. See [Name resolution using your own DNS server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server)

By default, app service use the Azure providing DNS server in the delegated VNet, it don't know your on-premise DNS records. You need to deploy a custom DNS server in your Azure virtual network and target network to forward the DNS query.

For Application Insights, you could check if you have a rule blocking the outbound call to application insights if you have set the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` to `1`. Refer to [this](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/06/17/General-Availability-of-VNet-Integration-with-Linux-Web-Apps.html).

> If you integrate your app with your VNet, the default behavior remains
> as it was. You would only be able to reach RFC1918 addresses
> (`10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16`) and service endpoints.
> Just like with Windows, the feature now supports outbound calls into
> the VNet on non-RFC1918 addresses as well. To reach all addresses you
> need to set the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` to `1`, your app will
> then enable all of the outbound traffic from your app to be subject to
> NSGs and UDRs.

Comment: thanks. First of all, you are right that we have created a new app service plan with the same name, but Linux OS Type. we did configure custom DNS in VNet and WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL in app service. it was working as expected with windows

During the Windows to Linux migration, we did not touch VNET configuration and we followed the below steps,
 1. Disconnect the Vnet-integration for all windows app services, then deleted all app services and plan itself
 2. Created a Linux ASP with the same name 
 3. Created a app service in the new ASP by enabling Vnet-Integration with

Comment: for now, we have raised Microsoft Support ticket. there are on it. no response yet from them.

Comment: When you disconnect the VNet integration with windows app, ensure that you have removed the delegation of service `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`, see [how to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-subnet-delegation#remove-subnet-delegation-from-an-azure-service-1). It seems just a DNS issue according to your description. You could first debug it refers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#debug-access-to-virtual-network-hosted-resources). Let me know if any clues?

Comment: Thanks for asking updates. No luck yet. currently, we have a Microsoft support ticket(still going on). initially, we were asked to collect TCPDUMP from app service, this says no response from custom DNS set in the vet. when we check with the on-primes DNS server team for the same, they say the DNS server works for everyone within the company. today the issue was replicated by our engineering team as well. and they had confirmed its from Microsoft side. so we gonna chase them back.